# photolouge gallery only uploads one picture

Tags: django, photologue

I have a django site with photologue installed, and I followed the official documentation to get it setup. Whenever I go to the admin site to create a gallery I can choose multiple pictures to put in that gallery but once I hit save only the first selected photo gets saved to the gallery. Does anyone know why this is happening. I'm using photologues default template to view my pictures on the front end.

Comment: This seems to be a bug at present with the Photologue admin - [see this ticket](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue/issues/150). I'm the package maintainer, and I've been unable to reproduce the bug. If you do find anything, could you please share on the Github ticket?

Comment: thanks for the response I'll try and give more details on the github page

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Looking at web debugger, when loading the gallery page, it says:

Loading failed for the  with source http://xxxxxxxx.com/static/sortedm2m/widget.js Loading failed for the  with source http://xxxxxx.com/static/sortedm2m/jquery-ui.js

I solved it by:

cd <static_dir>
cp -R .../python3.6/sortedm2m/static/sortedm2m .